# C++Winrt winmd visible in C# UWP project but not C++Winrt Project

Tags: uwp, idl, c++-winrt, winmd

I have some structs and enums in IDL file inside c++/winrt WRC project.

This is so the data structures can be shared between C++ and C#.

Add Winmd to UWP C# project and types are visible ok

Then on trying winrt projects

1. Winrt CoreApp Project builds fine after adding the winmd but never sees the types.
2. Winrt Blank Project fails to compile in some xaml related files due to my types , simply as result of adding winmd.

But no such issues with C# UWP project. In C# uwp i can see my type and use it no issues.

cheers

Comment: What does *"Winrt CoreApp Project [...] never sees the types"* mean? Do you get a compiler error instantiating those types? Are you using fully qualified type names? Are you using `using` statements? Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: Make sure to read [Consume APIs with C++/WinRT: If the API is implemented in a Windows Runtime component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/consume-apis#if-the-api-is-implemented-in-a-windows-runtime-component). If you have the [C++/WinRT VSIX extension](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt/vsix) installed, the projected types are generated automatically. You still need to `#include` the generated header file(s).

Comment: CoreApp builds fine after adding winmd, but does not know the types in winmd like i never added the refrence. BlankApp crashes during build, but build error is regarding types in winmd all works fine in C#. To reproduce create WinrtC++ WRC  IDL with struct inside. Try to reference from another winrt Blank or coreApp project.

Comment: Are you including the generated header files holding the projected types (assuming they are generated for you)? If they aren't generated, use the cppwinrt.exe tool to manually generate the header files from the Windows Runtime Component. It's still unclear, what *"CoreApp [...] does not know the types"* is supposed to mean. The app need not know them. Your code does, but we cannot see that code.

Comment: Error output from BlankApp  says it does not reognise type in my idl. The failure is from this line of code in winrt generated source const     
    &ActivateType<::winrt::IdlTest::BoxModel>, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr,
    1, // Object
    0, 0, -1, TypeKind::Metadata,
    TypeInfo_Flags_IsBindable | TypeInfo_Flags_None,
    //   3
    L"BlankApp1.MainPage", L"",
    &ActivateLocalType<::winrt::BlankApp1::implementation::MainPage>, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr,  inside file xamltypeinfo.g.cpp . would try to be more helpfull but its impossible to type anyhting in this narrow window

Comment: So there's an issue with your IDL then. At any rate, seeing a [mcve] would be very helpful.

Comment: I spotted this issue on my main project, and then created  empty project to test this. Can you try to reproduce. Its WRC with only a struct inside idl, any struct one variable in struct. I can access from C# UWP, cannot access from any c++-Winrt project.  The fact that i can access from C# atleast confirms the IDL is fine.

Comment: Hi if you try to reproduce this simple test, ps do so with /permissive- off. As you suggested the other i turn it off so winrt projects can build in enterprise.

Comment: This is the idl namespace IdlTest
{
 struct Linter
    {
    Int32 iSomeVal;

    };

    
}

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52299941/edit) your question to include all relevant information. It's unclear to me, why you are even referencing the IDL file in your BlankApp. You are (presumably) consuming a Windows Runtime Component, so all you need is the .winmd and .dll file.

Comment: Hi am not referencing the IDL, i am referencing the winmd, just  like i do to make it work for C# same exact procedure. You only reference winmd.The only way i can solve this issue now, is to refer winrt WRC winmd  from C# project, and directly refer the .h generated by IDL for Winrt project trying to access winrt WRC.

Answer (score 0):

So if C# can consume the types implemented in the WinRT component, it sounds like you may not have included a header file. Did you include the header file for the Windows Rutime Component in your `pch.h` file?

Let's say you have an windows runtime projected type called `Cat` that's in a Windows Runtime Component called `MyComponent`, if the name of your .winmd file is "MyComponent.winmd", do the following:

1. In your consuming project (your .exe, for example), add a reference to the .winmd file.
2. Build the project (must do this!)
3. Include a header for it in your `pch.h` file:

   `#include "winrt/MyComponent.h"   <-- don't forget!`

Once that's done, you should be able to find Cat (don't forget the namespace scope resolution, etc.)

```
// some consuming .cpp file

#include "pch.h"

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace MyComponent;    // <-- Add for convenience ...or not

App::App()
{
    Cat tabby();        // <-- Should work like a charm ;)
}
```